# Update Google Contacts with Delphi

Tags: rest, delphi, google-api, delphi-xe7

I'm trying to update **Google Contacts** through [Google Contacts API version 3.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) in **Delphi XE7**. I customized the RESTDemo Sample provided in http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE7/en/RESTDemo_Sample.

The instructions are (in Google Contacts API):

> To update a contact, first retrieve the contact entry, modify the data
>   and send an authorized PUT request to the contact's edit URL with the
>   modified contact entry in the body.

I'm able to retrieve the code, but unable to send the **PUT request**. The code is the following:

```
function TdmMain.UpdateName(sId, sName: string): string;
begin
    ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults;
    RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/' + sId + '/';
    RESTClient.Authenticator := OAuth2_GoogleContacts;
    RESTRequest.Execute;
    Result := Content;

    Content := AnsiReplaceStr(Content, '<title type="text"/>', '<title type="text">' + sName + '</title>');

// I don't know if I should repeat that, but I tried. Still, doesn't work
//    ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults;
//    RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/' + sId + '/';
//    RESTClient.Authenticator := OAuth2_GoogleContacts;
    RESTRequest.ClearBody;
    RESTRequest.AddBody(Content, ctTEXT_XML);
    RESTRequest.Method := rmPOST;
    RESTRequest.Execute;
    Result := Content;
end;
```

I'm getting everytime the following message:

```
> <html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
> charset=utf-8"> <title>Error 401 (Client Error)!!1</title> <style
> type="text/css"> ...
```

Does anyone know how to make a proper PUT request in Delphi?

Comment: Should that not be `rmPUT`?

Comment: @LURD I got the same error